# How to create permanent links to images with ActiveStorage and AWS Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage

I am building a Markdown Editor on the front end(React) and I need to upload an image and get back a permanent link for that image on my AWS S3 bucket.

I am using ActiveStorage and this is the code that I currently have:

```rb
    def upload_image
      image = ActiveStorage::Blob.create_and_upload!(io: params[:image], filename: ActiveStorage::Blob.generate_unique_secure_token).service_url

      render json: { link: image }, status: 200
    end
```

This creates a link that expires and is not permanent. How can I generate a link that is permanent?

If you have any suggestions on how to make this upload better please suggest some ideas. I don't have that much experience with uploading images to S3 with ActiveStorage.

Btw I am using API-only mode. Not sure if it is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: 'ap-south-1',access_key_id:Rails.application.credentials.aws[:access_key_id],secret_access_key: Rails.application.credentials.aws[:secret_access_key])
        bucket_name = Rails.application.credentials.db_backup[:bucket_name]
        file_name = "file_name.pdf"
        obj = s3.bucket(bucket_name).object(file_name)
        url = sell_user_details.inspection_report_url.to_s
        downloded_file = URI.parse(url).open
        obj.put(body: downloded_file, acl: 'public-read')
```

now you can get the url in **obj.public_url**